# Python Logging for a module shared by different scripts

Tags: python, logging

I like the python logging infrastructure and I want to use it for a number of different overnight jobs that I run.  A lot of these jobs use module X let's say.  I want the logging for module X to write to a log file not dependent on module X, but based on the job that ultimately led to calling functionality in module X.

So if overnight_script_1.py calls foo() in module X, I want the log of foo() to go to overnight_script_1.log.  I also want overnight_script_2.py's call of foo() to log to overnight_script_2.log.

A potential solution to this problem would be to set up the log file based on looking at the 0th argument to sys.argv which can be mapped to my preferred file.  Something seems hacky about doing it this way.  Is there a preferred design pattern for doing this? I don't want to rummage through different log files based on the module where the function was called to find my diagnostic information for one of my scripts.  Here is some code because I am not sure I am making myself clear.

Here is script1.py

```
import X
import logging_utils as lu
import sys

logname=sys.argv[0][:-3] # logname==script1 with the .py cut off
logger=lu.setup_logger(log_name) # assume this does the formatting and sets the filehandlers
# furthermore assume the file handler is set so that the output goes to script1.log.

# do a bunch of thing
logger.info('I am doing a bunch of things in script1 and I will now call X.foo()')
X.foo() # see module X below
logger.info('I finished X.foo()')
```

Similary, here is script2.py

```
import X
import logging_utils as lu
import sys

logname=sys.argv[0][:-3] # logname==script2 with the .py cut off
logger=lu.setup_logger(log_name) # assume this does the formatting and sets the filehandlers
# furthermore assume the file handler is set so that the output goes to script2.log.

# do a bunch of thing
logger.info('I am doing a bunch of things in script2 and I will now call X.foo()')
X.foo() # see module X below
logger.info('I finished X.foo()')
```

Here is X.py

```
import logging
import sys
logname=sys.argv[0][:-3] # could be script1 or script2
logger=logging.getLogger(logname)

def foo():
    try:
        i=1/0
    except:
        logger.error('oops - division by zero')
```

Then I want to run:

python script1.py

python script2.py

and get two log files script1.log and script2.log where the division by zero error that occurred in module X is logged in each.

Comment: Can you pass in the path of the log file to write to into foo() as a paramater?

Comment: @PrestonM - doesn't seem like the best solution to me.  I really have foo1, foo2, foo3, ... foo945, ... etc.

Comment: Usually you set up logging in the script you execute, not in the module itself, e.g. by calling `logging.basicConfig()` with the appropriate arguments. Where and how are you setting up logging handlers, formatters etc... currently?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The `X` modulo should *not* define any handler. The scripts are responsible for defining the handlers (either to a file, or to the console), set the level for logging and add the handlers to the logger... so the standard configuration already completely addresses the situation you are describing.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I have a centralized logging_util.py module that is used to set up the loggers.  Script_1.py would set up the logger with filehandler outputting to script_1.log.  This script calls into my library which has a couple hundred modules.  I want those modules that my script is using to know the correct file to write to.  When I get to module X in foo() and if it raises, I want logger.error('you screwed up') to go to script_1.log.  In other cases it should go to script_2.log.  I need X to get the correctly configured logger based on the script that ultimately called it.

Comment: `X` doesn't need to know where the logging output is going to. It just calls `log = logging.getLogger("X")` or equivalent to get it's logger and then uses that to log messages. If you use a `logging_utils` module to set up logging, then it should have a function you need to call from the script to initialize logging and set the right output file. It shouldn't set up logging on being imported, specially if other modules in your library also import it.

Comment: @mata - but won't that output to X.log (roughly - assume the name of the logger writes to the same name with .log appended)?  The function you are saying I need is indeed the main function of the util.  I will initialize the logging in script1.py with name=script1 and filehandler writing to script1.log.  Wouldn't module X require something like getLogger('script1') - or what I was roughly proposing getLogger(sys.argv[0])? I may have a fundamental misunderstanding - and maybe somehow getLogger('X') will know to write to script1.log?

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode No. The *handler* decides where the output goes, and you should not define handlers in `x` at all. You define handlers only in your scripts.

Comment: @Bakuriu to be clear - no handlers are defined in X.  I want to use getLogger from X with the correct name that has the handler that may have been set in any of script1, script2,..., script_n.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode Yes, that's *the wrong way* of doing it. See my answer. also read the 2-3 guides on logging on python.org (from which I've taken that schema).  I'm currently using this setup to handle logging in an application using `pika` and this works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you should just follow the standard set up for library code:

Say you have a package `mypkg` and you want this package to log information while letting the user of the package decide which level of logging to use and where the output should go.

The `mypkg` should **not** set the level nor any handler for the logs.
Module `x` of `mypkg` should be something like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def my_function():
    logger.info('something')
```

No configuration of the logging whatsoever just `getLogger(__name__)`.

Then your `script.py` that uses `mypkg` and wants to log at level `INFO` on the console will do:

```
import logging
import mypkg

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root_logger.addHandler(console_handler)

mypkg.my_function()  # produces output to stderr
```

While `script2.py` will log at level `DEBUG` to a file:

```
import logging
import mypkg


root_logger = logging.getLogger()
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('some_file.log')

root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
root_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

mypkg.my_function()
```

Note that by setting the level and handler on the root logger we are setting the level "globally". If the user has some own loggers that he wants to use with level `DEBUG` but he wants to use level `INFO` for `mypkg` he can do:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

mypkg_logger = logging.getLogger('mypkg')
mypkg_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = #... whatever you want
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

If your `mypkg` contains the modules `x.py`,  `y.py`, `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py` and you want to log the functions inside `x` at `DEBUG` and those inside `y` at `WARNING` and those for `a/b/c.py` at `INFO` you can do so by setting the levels on the corresponding loggers:

```
mypkg_logger = logging.getLogger('mypkg')
my_pkg_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

x_logger = logging.getLogger('mypkg.x')
x_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
y_logger = logging.getLogger('mypkg.y')
y_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Put the handlers only attached to the `root_logger` and everything should work fine.

---

Note: on some versions of python the `logging` module might warn you that you defined a logger with no handlers for the library modules. To fix ths you can use a `NullHandler` that just drops the logging messages:

```
# x.py

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

So the `NullHandler` literally does nothing, except from preventing the `logging` module from complaining. AFAIK newer versions do not need this at all.

Comment: Ahh so the key point that I seem to have been missing is that there is a root_logger which is the default return from getLogger() which we can modify from the calling script with a preferred FileHandler.  It appears that you are saying that getLogger(__name__) will then use this FileHandler until told otherwise.

Comment: Also I edited my original question to have code snippets.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode It's a bit more complicated. Loggers form a hierarchy based on their name so a logger with name `mypkg.x` is "a child" of the logger `mypkg`. Using `getLogger(__name__)` is just a simple way of calling your loggers `mypkg`, then `mypkg.x`, then `mypkg.y` then `mypkg.subpkg.x` etc. The root logger is a grandparent of all loggers. When you call `.info` or `.debug` on a logger the logger check if it matches its level, and if so it tries to log. If it doesn't find a handler it will send that item to the parent logger etc. up to the root logger.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode If you want to set the level on a per-module basis you can directly get the logger for that module and set the level there, this prevents messages with lower level to go up to the root logger.  Logging configuration can become really complicated since you have a level for each logger, logging propagation and you can also set the level of handlers...

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode You should probably read: [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html), [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging-cookbook.html), [Advanced logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial).

Comment: perfect - understood now.  It goes up the hierarchy until appropriate handlers are found with the rootlogger being the catch all.  I like that - convenient.  I think I get it now.

Comment: Next thing I will figure out when I have time (i.e. never) is how to dynamically modify the level - i.e. certain kind of error occurs and we set the level to debug all the way up the hierarchy...then watch all the info...I am sure that could be done in an except block - then how to dynamically go back to the warning level (or wherever) based on some signal (I don't know what that signal would be).

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use as many RotatingFileHandler(s) as different modules you have and setup their filenames accordingly

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html

-Edit-

Based on the comment then you may want to use a `Formatter` that takes into account where was the call made (to know if the call to the shared library was made from `module_1` or `module_2` and so on) and then and then simply log to the same file.

There are some caveats to think about:

- I'm not sure if there is order preservation in the writing of the file because there may be two or more processes that write to that file
- The log file may increase in size arbitrarily ending up with 0 disk space

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format

Comment: not sure I understand.  The rotating handlers appear to rotate based on log file sizes - or at least that seems like the intent.  Mainly I am trying to consolidate the logging for one of my scripts to a single log file - I don't want the logs for one app to be sprayed over many different log files.